# JavaScript selectors: how to find the next input field

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

After reading on selectors I've tried to apply a function to the next input field... But it doesn't work. Either I didn't get the idea of the used selectors or I get the wrong idea of the function word "this".

```
<table class="example" id="example">
<tr> <!-- rows are dynamically added -->
<td><input type="text" name="number" class="number"></td> 
<td><input type="text" name="name" class="name"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
    var searchTimeout;
    $(".number").keyup(function() {
    searchKey = this.value;
    clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
    searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    getdata(searchKey);    
    }, 200);
});
    
/* FIND A NAME MATCHING THE NUMBER */
    
    function getdata(searchKey) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'get_data.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {number: searchKey},
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.status) {
            $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".name").val(data.some_data);
            } else {
            $(this).closest("tr").next().find(".name").val("No match");
            }   
        }
    });         
    }
</script>
```

Data is fetched correctly but I can't display it since there's a problem with placing it in the proper field.

While experimenting I tried to change selector to:

```
$(input).closest.(".name").val(data.some_data);
```

and it worked - but it applied to all class "name" fields in all rows dynamically added below AND when I tried to enter data in the second "number" field - nothing happened (so I guess the selector at $(".number").keyup(function() is also incorrect).

Please, help me with this code so each row is treated as separate operation and the data displays in the properly selected field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call your function pass `this` as well which refer to input-box where event has been occured .So , outside settimeout add this line `var selector = this` then pass this here `getdata(searchKey ,selector)`  .Lastly change `$(this).clo..` to `$(el).closest..` same for other as well and no need of `next()` remove that .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var searchTimeout;
$(document).on('keyup', '.number', function() {
  searchKey = this.value;
  var selector = this //add this line
  clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
  searchTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    getdata(searchKey, selector); //pass that as well
  }, 200);
});

//add it here 
function getdata(searchKey, el) {
  /*$.ajax({
    url: 'get_data.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      number: searchKey
    },
    success: function(data) {*/
  //just for demo
  var data = {
    "status": "ok",
    "some_data": "abcgh"
  }
  if (data.status) {
    //remove next and use `el`
    $(el).closest("tr").find(".name").val(data.some_data);
  } else {
    $(el).closest("tr").find(".name").val("No match");
  }
  /*}
  });*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="example" id="example">
  <tr>
    <!-- rows are dynamically added -->
    <td><input type="text" name="number" class="number"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- rows are dynamically added -->
    <td><input type="text" name="number" class="number"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- rows are dynamically added -->
    <td><input type="text" name="number" class="number"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" class="name"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just perfect! :-) Thanks a lot. In fact I did try to pass "this" as a value to the function but due to other mistakes I thought it didn't work. As I see, I was close to solving the selector thing. I still need to read on 

$(document).on('keyup', '.number', function()

I guess this was the reasons for next rows to display repeated values. Once again - thank you! :-)

Comment: No , i have use `$(document)` because you said row are dynamically created so you need to bind your event handler with static elements which are already present inside your dom . It can be any element which is already exist in your html i.e : div , body ..etc